# How to make mosquitto broker auto-start on Mac OS (without homebrew)?

Tags: macos, launchd, daemons

I understand that using homebrew, a plist file will be provided and a user can use launchctl to install that plist file.

But, I am not using homebrew(nor macport). I built mosquitto binaries directly from mosquitto source distribution and I would like to be able to start mosquitto broker automatically (just like other daemons).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The homebrew mosquitto launch agent looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>homebrew.mxcl.mosquitto</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/usr/local/opt/mosquitto/sbin/mosquitto</string>
    <string>-c</string>
    <string>/usr/local/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
  <key>KeepAlive</key>
  <false/>
  <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
  <string>/usr/local/var/mosquitto</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Depending on your installation directory of mosquitto modify the two path strings in *ProgramArguments*  and the path of the *WorkingDirectory*.

Also modify the Label to org.user.mosquitto (to avoid future conflicts with a possíble homebrew mosquitto install) and then save the file as org.user.mosquitto.plist to ~/Library/LaunchAgents/.

Load the agent with `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/org.user.mosquitto.plist`.

---

Under certain circumstances (the make install options which you didn't specify in your question) it may be necessary to save the plist file to /Library/LaunchAgents (instead of ~/Library/LaunchAgents), modify permissions to root:wheel 644 and start it with:

```
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchAgents/org.user.mosquitto.plist
```

---

Now you can test the installation and ensure the server is running successfully.  Open a new command window and start a listener.

```
mosquitto_sub -t topic/state
```

In another window, send a message to the listener.

```
mosquitto_pub -t topic/state -m "Hello World"
```

Comment: thank you.  One thing not mentioned in your answer is to ensure the WorkingDirectory given in the plist file exists.  Another thing is that I used `launchctl list | grep mosquitto` and check the first field (should be a valid pid) to see if the mosquitto broker is successfully launched.

Comment: @TzunghsingDavidWong Hmm I didn't state it explicitly but implicitly: "Depending on your installation directory of mosquitto modify the two path strings in [...] the path of the WorkingDirectory."  ;-)

Comment: my bad... overlooked that point.  In my case, I didn't install anything.  I simply recovered mosquitto binaries and shared libraries from a time-machine backup and dropped them into my /usr/local.  And they just work 8-)